# acejump in sublimetext3,the shortcuts has been used. what should i do

Tags: sublimetext3

I have install acejump in sublime text3. but the keyboard shortcuts"ctrl+;" has been used.

[image]

so  what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [readme page](https://github.com/ice9js/ace-jump-sublime), at the bottom you'll find the command names that are used by AceJump.
What you need to do, is simply assign that command to a different key combination in your user key binding preferences, like this:

```
[
    { "keys": ["your_key_combination"], "command": "ace_jump_word"},
    ...
]
```

I'm glad you took interest in my plugin, and I hope this solves your issue.